# What is the best solution to hide the ugly Gwt Crawlable Url (the one use hashbang)?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I  just discovered that google adword does not allow the hash bang (`#`) in the destination url of Adword Ads. If the url contains `#` then u can't advertise ur page in Google.

So we need a way to hide the hash bang (`#`) in the url but still be able to let the the spider to know that our app is the Ajax-based app.

So what is the best (ie simple but very effective) solution to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a redirect: Google Groups for instance uses redirects for its "permalinks"; e.g. https://groups.google.com/d/forum/google-web-toolkit redirects to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-web-toolkit

Comment: Hi Thomas, that's great direction, but How can implement the redirection properly? Do i need to create a new DB table or does GWTP have a way to handle this automatically? I think if GWTP can handle the redirection then it will be better than storing redirection info in DB

Comment: Use a naming pattern. For instance, Google Groups maps `/d/<whatever>` to `/forum/#!<whatever>`; so you'd just need a servlet listening at `/d` and using [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29) to use after the `#!`. Simple and effective.

Comment: Hi I have used the #! for sharing my URL but my end result was not good and my URL was not become sharable. I have do this through creating the history class and changing the og tag dynamically I have passed the string as --  private static final String question = "!question"; so that my url become www......./#!question . I have tested my URL in facebook debbuger and find that the url after #! is not taking by this. Please help me to get out from this