# URL without hash (#) in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, url-rewriting

In **GWT** i need to use **#** in **URL**, in order to navigate from one page to another for eg. www.abc.com/#questions/10245857 but due to which i am facing problem in sharing the url.
Google scrappers are reading the url only before # i.e. www.abc.com.

Now i want to remove # from my url and want to keep it straight as www.abc.com/question/10245857.

I am unable to do so. Please help me with some links or code.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you want URLs that don't use the *hash*, then you have to use HTML5 `pushState` ([browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/history)).

You cannot do that if you use the `History` class directly; you'd have to create your own `History` class that use `pushState` and use that class in your code instead of the GWT built-in one.

If you use Places, then it's much easier as all you have to do is implement an `Historian` rather than use the `DefaultHistorian`; e.g. https://gist.github.com/tbroyer/1883821

If you need to support browsers that don't have `pushState`, then things get much more complex.

There are alternatives though:

- you can use `#!` and implement the necessary server-side hooks: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/ (there are projects that implement this by running your GWT app within an HTMLUnit pseudo-browser on the server; IIRC, GWT-Platform has such a feature)
- you can provide permalinks to your "places", like Google Maps or Google Groups do; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24717441/116472

Answer (score 0):

The # represents places inside the application so to change the URL try Creating different GWT entry point modules  could solve this issue – there would be only one web application this time, but each module would be accessible via a different URL. Look into this article http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2011/02/22/structuring-gwt-modules-for-large-applications/